# graphvizで作成したグラフの図を商用目的の（広告をつけた）スマホアプリに掲載して公開することに著作権上の問題はありますか。

Tags: ライセンス, graphviz

graphvizで作成したグラフの図を商用目的の（広告をつけた）スマホアプリに掲載して公開することに著作権上の問題はありますか。
また、copyrightの表示が必要な場合どのように書けば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

この回答に従った結果損害を被っとしても、回答者はその当該損害に関して一切責任を負いません。
…という、ライセンスや法律関係でお決まりの文言を宣言した上で回答します。

---

まず著作権についてですが、著作権が発生する著作物は「思想又は感情を創作的に表現したものであつて、文芸、学術、美術又は音楽の範囲に属するもの」と、 [著作権法 第二条第一項](https://elaws.e-gov.go.jp/document?lawid=345AC0000000048#Mp-At_2-Pr_1) で定義されています。

ツールの利用によって機械的に行われた変換は、創作的ではないので、著作物には当たらないというのが、一般的な見解です。

例えば、小説を書くのに、ワープロソフトを使ったり、文字変換に IME ソフトを使いますが、 これらのソフトは、できあがった小説に対して著作権が発生しません。
Graphviz も、あくまで Graphviz の dot言語 のソースコードを図に機械的に変換するものなので、その変換に関しては著作権は発生しないと考えて良いでしょう。

つまり、 **Graphviz に喰わせる dot言語 のソースコードがあなたが創造したもの**などであり著作権上の問題がないのであれば、**それを変換して出力したグラフの図も著作権上の問題はない**と言えそうです。

一方で、 Graphviz のソフトウェアそのもの（ないしソースコード）を、スマホアプリ内に埋め込む場合は、話が変わってくるのでお気をつけください。

---

一方で、ソフトウェアの利用に当たっては、著作権とは別に「**ライセンス**」に従うことも重要です。
こちらは、著作権のような法律の話ではなく、ソフトの著作者と利用者の2者間の契約の話になります。

※: その著作権が存在するからこそ、そのソフトの著作者はそのソフトの利用許諾条件を決められるので、著作権の法律と関係があるにはあります。

Graphviz のバージョンにもよりますが、現在のバージョンのライセンスは以下のページに明記されています。これに従う限り、利用上の問題は無いと考えて良いでしょう。
https://graphviz.org/license/

詳しい内容は上記ライセンス内容を読んでいただくべきですが、少なくとも Graphviz の出力物について、商用利用を禁止すると言った制限はなさそうです。

当然、「Graphviz の利用に当たっての損害等に対するすべての責任は除外される」などといった、ライセンス内のいくつかの条件には従う必要があります。